# how to include hard-coded value to output from mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've created a **MySQL sproc** which returns 3 separate result sets.  I'm implementing the npm mysql package downstream to exec the sproc and get a result structured in json with the 3 result sets.  I need the ability to filter the json result sets that are returned based on some type of indicator in each result set.  For example, if I wanted to get the result set from the json response which deals specifically with Suppliers then I could use some type of js filter similar to this:

```
var supplierResultSet = mySqlJsonResults.filter(x => x.ResultType === 'SupplierResults');
```

I think SQL Server provides the ability to include a hard-coded column value in a SQL result set like this:

```
select
'SupplierResults',
*
from
supplier
```

However, this approach appears to be invalid in MySQL b/c MySQL Workbench is telling me that the sproc syntax is invalid and won't let me save the changes.  Do you know if something like what I'm trying to achieve is possible in MySQL and if not then can you recommend alternative approaches that would help me achieve my ultimate goal of including some type of fixed indicator in each result set to provide a handle for downstream filtering of the json response?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a [mcve], see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Also include the complete error message you get from MySQL.

Comment: Try `select
'SupplierResults',
supplier.*
from
supplier`

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you just need to prefix `*` with the table name or alias:

```
select 'SupplierResults' hardcoded, s.* from supplier s
```

As far as I know, this is the SQL Standard. `select *` is valid only when no other expression is added in the `selec` clause; SQL Server is lax about this, but most other databases follow the standard.

It is also a good idea to assign a name to the column that contains the hardcoded value (I named it `hardcoded` in the above query).

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, in your case, in your query you would need to do this

```
select
'SupplierResults',
supplier.*  -- <-- this
from
supplier
```

Try this

```
create table a (f1 int);
insert into a values (1);
select 'xxx', f1, a.* from a;
```

Basically, if there are other fields in select, prefix '*' with table name or alias

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can simply put the `*` first:

```
SELECT *, 'SupplierResults'
FROM supplier
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b729790285be0e0c912aff9a22d52be8)